# Image Upload function adds++(+1) copies to next upload. What is wrong or how to reset the "selectedImage"

Tags: javascript, uiimageview, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

This ImageUpload function works, but it keep on adding on in copies each time I upload a new photo. That i not what I want. When I upload the first image, it work as it should. One image is uploaded to my server. But when I continue by choosing or taking a new photo, it uploads two copies of the same photo. The third image I upload becomes uploaded tree times, the next four times and so it grows in copies uploaded each time. Only if I restart the app, it starts from one copy upload again. I hope someone can see whats wrong or how I can reset the "selectedImage" after a upload process.

```
//this variable will hold the image data blob from the device's gallery or camera
    var selectedImage = null;

    var buttonSelectImage = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        width:240,
        height:50,
        top:242,
        title:'Select image'
    });

    buttonSelectImage.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        dialog.show();
    });

    var buttonUpload = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        width:240,
        height:50,
        top:304,
        title:'Send to site'
    });

    //our dialog with the options of where to get an image from
    var dialog = Titanium.UI.createOptionDialog({
        title: 'Choose source...',
        options: ['Camera','Album','Cansel'],
        cancel:2
    });

    //Dialog event listener
    dialog.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        Ti.API.info('You selected… ' + e.index);
        if(e.index == 0){
        //from the camera
        Titanium.Media.showCamera({
        success:function(event){
        selectedImage = event.media; 
        if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO){
        imageThumbnail.image = selectedImage;
        win.add(imageThumbnail);            
        }
        buttonUpload.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        if(selectedImage != null) {
        postToSite();
        }else{
        alert('You must choose a image!');
        }
        });
        win.add(buttonUpload);
        buttonUpload.show();
        },
        cancel:function(){
        //getting image from camera was cancelled
        },
        error:function(error){
        // create alert
        var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Camera'});
        // set message
        if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA){
        a.setMessage('Your cellphone lack the camera function!');
        }else{
        a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
        }
        // show alert
        a.show();
        },
        allowImageEditing:true,
        saveToPhotoGallery:true
        });
        }
        else if(e.index == 1){
        //obtain an image from the gallery
        Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
        success:function(event){
        selectedImage = event.media;
        // set image view
        Ti.API.debug('Our type was: '+event.mediaType);
        if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO){
        // set image view
        imageThumbnail.image = selectedImage;
        win.add(imageThumbnail);
        }
        buttonUpload.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        if(selectedImage != null) {
        postToSite();
        }else{
        alert('You must choose a image!');
        }
        });
        win.add(buttonUpload);
        buttonUpload.show();        
        },
        cancel:function(){
        //user cancelled the action fron within the photo gallery
        }
        });
        }else{
        //cancel was tapped user opted not to choose a photo
        }
    });
    win.add(buttonSelectImage);

    function randomString(length,current){
    current = current ? current : '';
    return length ? randomString( --length , "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt( Math.floor( Math.random() * 60 ) ) + current ) : current;
    }
    //Post to server
    function postToSite(){
        //create the httpRequest
        var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
        xhr.onerror = function(e)
            {
                Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Error', message:e.error}).show();
                Ti.API.info('IN ERROR ' + e.error);
            };
            xhr.setTimeout(40000);
            
        xhr.onsendstream = function(e){
                
                ind.value = e.progress ;
                Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + e.progress);
                ind.show();
            };
                
        // Get the sessionID
        var sessionId = Titanium.App.Properties.getString("sessionId");
        
        //open the httpRequest
        xhr.open('POST','http://example.com/index.php?include=app_support/upload.php&session_id='+sessionId);
            activityIndicator.show();
            buttonUpload.hide();
        xhr.onload = function(){
            //the image upload method has finished
            var json = this.responseText;
            var response = JSON.parse(json);
            if (response.auth == 'false'){
                alert('User validation failed');
            }
            else if (response.upload_status == 'success'){
                ind.hide();
                activityIndicator.hide();
                buttonUpload.hide();
                alert(response.message);
            }else{
                ind.hide();
                activityIndicator.hide();
                buttonUpload.show();
                alert(response.message);
            }
        };
        //send the data
        var r = randomString(5) + '.jpg';
        xhr.send({'form_data[file][value]': selectedImage, 'value': r});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the source of your problem:

```
dialog.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
...
  buttonUpload.addEventListener('click', function(e){
```

You are adding a click listener in some click event. Therefore, every time the first click event is executed, another click event will be added to buttonUpload and executed as many times as the first click event is called.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I deleted one of the buttonUpload eventListeners and moved the other outside of the dialogEventListener and now the function works as I wanted it to. Thank you again.